# Updating makes the UI slow

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, ios9

Each page of a UIPageViewController contains 6 views, and each view contains a ProgressBar to show the download progress running in the background.

Each time, the download progress will update the UI about 1% percent more during 0.01 second (that's what I guess). Because we have 6 views, so there are too much updates on UI on each page, and it makes the UI quite slow when you want to navigate to another page.

I am using NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download a file, and then update the UI on main thread:

```
//- on main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //- update UI
    ...
}
```

The following is what I log for each update, including the time.

```
...
2015-08-25 14:42:42.524 MyApp[896:230684] Feedback = On Downloading ...
2015-08-25 14:42:42.543 MyApp[896:230684] Feedback = On Downloading ...
2015-08-25 14:42:42.567 MyApp[896:230683] Feedback = On Downloading ...
2015-08-25 14:42:42.590 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Downloading ...
...
2015-08-25 14:42:44.134 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Unzipping ...
2015-08-25 14:42:44.139 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Unzipping ...
2015-08-25 14:42:44.149 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Unzipping ...
2015-08-25 14:42:44.159 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Unzipping ...
...
2015-08-25 14:42:45.962 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Parsing ...
2015-08-25 14:42:45.964 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Parsing ...
2015-08-25 14:42:45.966 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = On Parsing ...
...
2015-08-25 14:42:46.071 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = Finish Parsing Tags XML file
2015-08-25 14:42:46.072 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = Parse Tags XML file successfully
2015-08-25 14:42:46.072 MyApp[896:230753] Feedback = Handle Package Successfully
```

Is there anyway to make it faster?

Thanks,

Note: I am developing iPad application, XCode7, ios9, objective-C

Comment: What method are you using to update the "UI"? What part of the UI are you updating? Typically, UIPageViewController will not redraw views that are not currently visible.

Comment: Also make sure that all the UI update run on the main thread.

Comment: I am using NSURLSession, and NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download a file and update the UI on main thread using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...}. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that it's the progress updates causing you trouble, you can just update a number that represents the progress amount -- in the background -- and then set a timer to read the number(s) and perform UI updates in the foreground.

How frequently does the user need to see changes?  ...half a second?  ...one second?

(`NSURLSession` does seem more "chatty" than necessary.)

Comment: NSURLSession will update the UI depending on the new amount of bytes it fetches at a time. So, I cannot say how frequently it updates. What I did is to compare the old percent value and the new percent value. If the difference is let say 5%, I will let the NSURLSession update the UI. However, with this solution, the progressbar is not running smoothly, looks like an intermittent process.

Comment: That's basically what I was suggesting except you're using amount instead of frequency.  There's always going to be a trade-off between the amount of work you do on the main thread and the responsiveness.  (On the other hand, have you used Instruments or something to measure where the app is actually spending its time?)

Comment: I don't use the Instrutments, but the logging console to see actually how much time for each update. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I'll just repeat my answer that nobody needs visual feedback about progress every .01 or .002 seconds.  Cache the progress information and update the UI on a timer.

Comment: Provided that the updates are really causing the unresponsiveness (Instruments is your friends there) it probably may pay to tinker with the frequency until you get a nice balance. One approach would be to keep some kind of timestamp per progress bar in order to not update any progress bar that has been updated less than some set time ago. Say 0.25 seconds initially.  You then have a parameter you can tinker with to get the right balance between responsiveness and smoothness. You may have to special case for the 100% case though so the progress bar "finishes" properly under all circumstances.